# Rails Mailer - Can't access instance variable from Mailer View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, instance-variables, mailer

I have a rails mailer that currently sends an email successfully anytime a user replies to another user's comment.  (the email goes to the person who was replied to).  I'm trying to add some dynamic content in the email body like the username of the person who replied and that user's comment itself.  I'm not sure how to grab that particular comment within the new_reply.html.erb view so that it shows correctly in my email that is being sent...my code is as follows:

views/comment_mailer/new_reply.html.erb (email content)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table width="100%">

        <h2 style="color: #428bca">You have a new reply.</h2>
            <p>Someone replied with the following comment...</p>

      <p><%= comment.body %></p>

            <p>To reply back, login to the app...</p>

        </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

views/comments/_comment.html.erb (the actual comment view in the app)

```
<div class="well">
  <p class="text-muted">Added on
    <%= l(comment.created_at, format: '%B, %d %Y %H:%M:%S') %></p>

  <blockquote>
    <p><%= comment.body %></p>
        <p><%= link_to 'reply', new_comment_path(comment.id) %></p>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

mailers/comment_mailer.rb (my comment mailer)

```
class CommentMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: "notifications@app.com"

    def new_reply(parent_comment)
    owner = parent_comment.owner
        mail(to: owner.email, subject: 'New reply to one of your comments')
    end
end
```

controllers/model_comments_controller.rb (controller for these comments)

```
def create
    @taskrelationship = commentable_type.constantize.find(commentable_id)
    @project = @taskrelationship.taskproject
    @new_comment = Comment.build_from(@taskrelationship, current_user.id, body)
    if @new_comment.save

      # create the notification
      (@taskrelationship.taskproject.followers.uniq - [current_user]).each do |user|
        Notification.create(recipient: user, actor: current_user, action: "posted", notifiable: @new_comment)
      end

      make_child_comment
    end
    render 'projects/show_project_task_comments', layout: false
  end

private

def make_child_comment
  return if comment_id.blank?

  parent_comment = Comment.find comment_id
  @new_comment.move_to_child_of(parent_comment)
  CommentMailer.new_reply(parent_comment).deliver
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `new_reply` method in the mailer declare an instance variable @comment that references the comment you'll like to use.

Then in the template, just use @comment to reference it.

Comment: Thanks...so essentially just @comment = Comment.last

Comment: I tried that and then did <p><%= @comment.body %></p> in the template but thats not working.  Sorry i'm a little tired...know i'm missing something stupid.

Comment: disregard...i just placed it after the 'mail' line, when it should've gone before that line.  thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome, hope it helped